# Wordpress: can't run update script in PHP returned table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I am an absolute beginner in PHP. In my Wordpress page I need to:

1. input name or/and select country and city (`ajax_select_city_js__`)
2. click search button
3. result is a table, I add one plus update button in every column;
   the mobile and email columns are editable
   I can't realize:
4. Ex. I change a mobile number and when I click to change button I
   want to execute update script in MySQL. I try `onclick` method but I
   can't do it (button value equal UPDATE part).

Because I have error when I want to post I put all into the [follow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGU1t.jpg).

Wordpress main page:

```
[php] include '/select_list_city.php'; [/iphp]
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" /><script src="/ajax_select_city.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm" action="/userlnfo-modify.php" method="post">
            Név*:<br><input type="text" name="nev">
            <p> [php] echo $re_html;[/php]<br class="clear" />
            <br class="clear" />
            <button id="sub">Search</button>
            <br><br></form><span id="result"></span>
            <div id="data"><?php echo $result; ?></div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/my_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </Form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is a part of `userlnfo-modify.php`:

```
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $ID = $ID+1;
    $data_name = $data["name"];

    echo'
    <tr style="background-color:#EFFBFB; border: 1px solid black;">
    <td style="font-size:14px;">'.$data["name"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:14px;">'.$data["city"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:14px;">'.$data["age"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:14px;">'.$data["utca"].'</td>
    <td><input type="text" value='.$data["mobil"].'></td>
    <td><input type="text" value='.$data["email"].'></td>
    <td onclick="cellOnclick()"><a href="#" onclick="linkOnclick()" style="text-decoration: none;">
    <input type=button value="UPDATE" myFunction(this);return false;"></button></td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}

unset all variable...
```

[image: Printscreen image: top:before search by name or/and country,city; below table result]